# Sending messages in discord.py @tasks.loop()

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, replit

**Goal:**

I am simply trying to send a message to a discord channel from a `@tasks.loop()` without the need for a discord message variable from `@client.event async def on_message`. The discord bot is kept running in repl.it using uptime robot.

**Method / Background:**

A simple `while True` loop in will not work for the larger project I will be applying this principle to, as detailed by [Karen's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63846957/16402702). I am now using `@tasks.loop()`  which Lovesh has quickly detailed here: [(see Lovesh's work)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66753449/16402702).

**Problem:**

I still get an error for using the [most common method to send a message in discord using discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel). The error has to have something to do with the `await channel.send( )` method. Neither of the messages get sent in discord. [Here is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXvHX.jpg).

**Code:**

```
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import os
from keep_alive import keep_alive
import time

token = os.environ['goofyToken']




# Set Up Discord Client & Ready Function
client = discord.Client()
channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL-ID)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))



@tasks.loop(count=1)
async def myloop(word):
  
  await channel.send(word)




@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  msg = message.content
  
  if msg.startswith('!'):

    message_to_send = 'Hello World!'
    await channel.send(message_to_send)
  

    myloop.start(message_to_send)
    


keep_alive()
client.run(token)
```

**Attempted Solutions:**

A message can be sent from the `on_message` event using the syntax `await message.channel.send('Hello World!)`. However, I just can't use this. The code is kept running online by [uptimerobot](https://uptimerobot.com/), a free website which pings the repository on repl.it. When the robot pings the repository, the message variable is lost, so the loop would stop scanning my data in the larger project I am working on which is giving me this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using any `client.get_*` method the bot will try to grab the object *from the cache*, the `channel` global variable is defined *before* the bot actually runs (so the cache is empty). You should get the channel *inside* the loop function:

```py
@tasks.loop(count=1)
async def myloop(word):
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send(word)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!